# How to stylize the tooltip in a Bootstrap theme?

Tags: 7, theming

I've been requested to stylize a tooltip in a Drupal 7 bootstrap theme. I have no idea how to get one going other than hard-coding it all in the web dev tools. Is there a setting in Drupal 7 to turn on tooltips for specific images or text??

Comment: Your question is a bit vague. General good practice here is to explain what you have tried, what docs you have looked at etc. to make it easier for others to give you helpful answers.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you correctly, then you're probably after [bootstrap tooltips](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/components/tooltips/).
If your site is already using the bootstrap theme, then all you would need to do (if it's not already done) is attaching the tooltip functionality via client side javascript code, e.g.:

```
$(YOUR_SELECTOR).tooltip();
```

So if every element in your markup that should use a bootstrap tooltip has the CSS class "tooltip" that would be:

```
$('.tooltip').tooltip();
```

See the docs that I have linked above for more options for the tooltip configuration. As for the styling, there are multiple answers to that on stackoverflow:

- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43773725/bootstrap-tooltips-with-different-styles
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17642447/change-bootstrap-tooltip-color